# Aestan Tray Menu Error while installing WAMP

Tags: wamp

Installed latest vesrion of WAMP Server(32 bits and php 5.4)2.4..
then installed VC10 SP1 vcredist_x86.exe 32 bits.
still when i click on WAMP icon..it says "Aestan Tray Menu has encountered a problem and needs to close.  We are sorry for the inconvenience"
Please Help

edit :solved it by installing .net frama work.thank you everyone

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have the latest version of all of these Microsoft C++ Redistributable runtime libraries.

The 2008 Redist is used by wampmanager

The 2010 Redist is used by some versions of Apache ( depending on compiler used )

The 2012 Redist is used by some versions of Apache ( depending on compiler used )

**FOR WAMP 32bit**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=8328)

If you are using WampServer 2.4
[Microsoft Visual C++ 2012, And select vcredist_x86.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

**FOR WAMP 64bit**

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=5582)

***Yes you need the x86 Package regardless***

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15336)

[Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 SP1 Redistributable Package (x64)](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=13523)

If you are using WampServer 2.4
[eMicrosoft Visual C++ 2012, And select vcredist_x64.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=30679)

Comment: All installed. Still does not work.
(I've Windows7 x64 and I've tried both x64 and x86).

Comment: Try adding the VC 2005 redist as well.

Comment: It was enough VC 2010 and disable Antivirus for a while. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable temporally your Antivirus.

(After a day of trouble I've disabled all Kaspersky activity and everything started to work, also re-enabling Kaspersky....)